# C++ Clean successful, Build failed, directory missing?

Tags: c++, makefile

so I'm a beginner in C++ and just had this error message, the Clean goes sucessful and the build fails for whatever reason, nothings red or so. I don't really know what to do in this case. I've checked my libraries and paths and they are fine, the lines that's are shown don't really make sense, since all the lines are blank. Can anyone help me figure out what was going wrong?

```
cd 'Z:\NetBeansProjects\Zahldarstellung2'
C:\msys\bin\make.exe -f Makefile CONF=Debug clean
"/C/msys/bin/make.exe" -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk QMAKE= SUBPROJECTS= .clean-conf
make.exe[1]: Entering directory `/z/NetBeansProjects/Zahldarstellung2'
rm -f -r build/Debug
rm -f dist/Debug/MinGW-Windows/zahldarstellung2.exe
make.exe[1]: Leaving directory `/z/NetBeansProjects/Zahldarstellung2'

CLEAN SUCCESSFUL (total time: 450ms)
cd 'Z:\NetBeansProjects\Zahldarstellung2'
C:\msys\bin\make.exe -f Makefile CONF=Debug
"/C/msys/bin/make.exe" -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk QMAKE= SUBPROJECTS= .build-conf
make.exe[1]: Entering directory `/z/NetBeansProjects/Zahldarstellung2'
"/C/msys/bin/make.exe"  -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk dist/Debug/MinGW-Windows/zahldarstellung2.exe
make.exe[2]: Entering directory `/z/NetBeansProjects/Zahldarstellung2'
mkdir -p build/Debug/MinGW-Windows
rm -f "build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/GanzeZahl.o.d"
g++    -c -g -include . -MMD -MP -MF "build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/GanzeZahl.o.d" -o build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/GanzeZahl.o GanzeZahl.cpp
cc1plus.exe: fatal error: .: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk:67: recipe for target `build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/GanzeZahl.o' failed
make.exe[2]: *** [build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/GanzeZahl.o] Error 1
make.exe[2]: Leaving directory `/z/NetBeansProjects/Zahldarstellung2'
nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk:60: recipe for target `.build-conf' failed
make.exe[1]: *** [.build-conf] Error 2
make.exe[1]: Leaving directory `/z/NetBeansProjects/Zahldarstellung2'
nbproject/Makefile-impl.mk:39: recipe for target `.build-impl' failed
make.exe": *** [.build-impl] Error 2

BUILD FAILED (exit value 2, total time: 654ms)
```

Appreciate some help
Greets

Comment: Looks like the problem is `-include .`

Answer (score 1):

The `-include` option is used as a way to include a specific file into the current source file. Using e.g. `-include somefile.h` is the same as doing `#include "somefile.h"` at the top of the source file.

The problem here is that you try to include a complete directory, not a single file. This is not valid.

I *guess* what you really want is the `-I` option which adds a *path* to the list of paths to search for system header files.

Comment: Thanks a lot! My mates said we can just include a directory, didn't know that doesn't work. Guess that'll help in the future